# Can i resize Chrome window using the console?

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to resize the Chrome window using the developer tool's console? If so, what would the command be? becuase the window.resizeTo(w,h) didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official Chrome [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2091) says:

> By Design we don't support resize/move for tabs, only constrained windows.

Windows in Chrome can be resized via [Chrome extensions API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-update), however it's not available from console. You should probably try using one of [many 'window resizing' extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/resize%20window?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher). In the near future it will be possible for extensions to add own console commands, however as for now it's an [experimental](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/experimental.devtools.console.html) feature.

Comment: Thank you, apreciate your help

Comment: That page talks about pages setting the window size, not setting it from the developer console.

Comment: The developer console processes commands that can either access extensions (which are consequently when enabled added to the DOM of that page) or commands/javascript in relation to that page. So yes, the answer above is applicable and correct

Answer (score 2):

i think you can only resize windows that's you have created from the console, like popups
for example:

```
var pop=window.open("","","width=1024,height=768");
pop.resizeTo(100,100);
```

Answer (score 1):

On macOS you can run: `open -a Google\ Chrome --args --window-size=1366,768`

Answer (score 0):

> Since Firefox 7, it's no longer possible for a web site to change the default size of a window in a browser, according to the following rules:

- You can't resize a window or tab that wasn’t created by `window.open.`
- You can't resize a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than one tab.

found on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.resizeTo#Notes

some try and error seems to prove that these rules also apply in Chrome.